# jQuery.ajax({type:&#39;POST&#39; in grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

First of all thanks to you all for your valuable suggestion.I got stuck one problem that is in jQuery ajax call in grails remote function call on controller.
The plug-ins installed in my project are: jQueryUi - 1.10.3, jQuery - 1.11.0.

My controller this method:

```
def loadamount(){...}
```

And for ajax call method:

```
def ajaxCallBalance(long id){
    def userBalances=loadamount(id)
    def userBalance=userBalances[0] //it returns in array
    return [usreBalance:userBalance]
}
```

These are nothing but my database call to load user amount in his a/c that should load on page load inside user profile html page. So for that i use this:

Point 677:

```
<g:if test="${session.LogedUser}">
<script>
    ${remoteFunction(
        controller:'user',
        action:'ajaxCallBalance',
        update:[success:'uresult',failure:'uresult'],
        id:session.LogedUser.id
    )}
</script>
```

In HTML:

```
<li id="uresult"><!-- Want to see hare what result either value or error it returns --></li>
```

In firebug console I see get this error:

> SyntaxError: syntax error

```
<script>

jQuery.ajax({
   type:&#39;POST&#39;,
 
   url:&#39;/...../..../ajaxCallBalance/10000000&#39;,

   success:function(data,textStatus) {jQuery(&#39;#uresult&#39;).html(data);},

   error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) 

   jQuery(&#39;#uresult&#39;).html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);

}

});

</script>
```

[Note:This is generated by grails ajax plugin what i have wrote is see point 677.]

Here is my Question:

1. Why is this `$#39;` appearing even though I have no space, nor any symbol. Is it a bug or my mistake?
2. Is there any way to handle this kind of scenario as user `onLoad/(document).ready()` call for such conditions. If Yes, then what I will do?

Comment: Please copy the complete error you're getting, there has to be more to that line...

Comment: post your jQuery ajax function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use the grails construct of `${remoteFunction...}` in js directly. use ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "${createLink(action:'ajaxCallBalance', controller:'user')}",
   data: { id: id },

  success: function (dataCheck) {
    //Do stuff
  }

  ........
});
```

or use g:remoteFunction like this way

```
$('mydiv').onclick = <g:remoteFunction action="ajaxCallBalance" controller="user" id="${id}" />
```

Comment: Thanks emilan,It works.there is one point also i want to mention that the ajax as mention have to use and for dataCheck value we have to provide from controller method that also should be render not return.